# Only allow a specific peripheral to be connected to a USB port

Tags: usb, linux, webcam, security, peripherals

I am turning my raspberry pi prototype device into a market product. The data and the program running on the pi must be protected. But we have a USB webcam attached to it (provided by us, hence we know its details, id, etc). So I want to ensure that the end-user doesn't plug anything (keyboard, mouse, pen drives, etc) into the USB port except that particular webcam. How can I accomplish this?

Note: I don't want the overhead labour of desoldering the USB port and connector, and soldering the webcam's bare wires on to the pi. That would be the last resort.

Comment: This may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment

Comment: Hot glue is probably easiest. Glue your camera to your RPi. Glue a blank USB plug into the other three sockets to prevent anything alien being inserted.

Comment: @Craig Thanks! That was exactly what I had been looking for. Would it disable ethernet access over USB as well (through a USB data cable)?
If yes, can you please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[udev rules](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev) are probably the best way to handle this. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment) is probably a good starting point.

Basically you would create a rule that matches all devices except yours and have udev disable the device when it is added.